# Generating Functions - Counting how many solutions for an exact $x^n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, generating-functions

Having trouble with this problem:

$$ x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6 = 13 $$
$$ x\ne 3 $$

Thanks in advance for any further help.

Being able to get to this point:
$$\begin{split}
f(x) &= (x^0+x^1+x^2+x^4+x^5+\cdots)^6\\
&= [(-x^3)+{x^0+x^1+x^2+(x^3)+x^4+x^5+\cdots}]^6\\
&= \left[{(-x^3)} + \frac{1}{(1-x)}\right]^6\\
&=\left[ \frac{-x^3(1-x)+1}{(1-x)}\right]^6\\
&=\left[\frac {x^4-x^3+1}{1}\cdot\frac {1}{1-x}\right]^6\\
&=(x^4-x^3+1)^6 \frac {1}{(1-x)^6}\\
\end{split}$$

Now if I long divide $(x^4-x^3+1)$ with $(1-x)$ I get  $[(-x^3 + \frac {1}{1-x}) (1-x)]^6 $ thus:
$$\begin{split}
f(x)&=\left(\frac {1}{1-x} -x^3\right)^6  \frac {(1-x)^6}{(1-x)^6}\\
&=\left(\frac {1}{1-x} -x^3\right)^6\\
\end{split}$$

That's where I get stuck, honestly.

Comment: What are you seeking for ?

Comment: @EDX At the top from what it says, OP seeks the number of compositions of $13$ into $6$ nonnegative parts, where none of the parts is $3.$ [I haven't checked the attempt at generating function use.]

Comment: This is a combinatorics question whereas you can solve with divide & conquer or with generating functions. During my studies, I always try both. I could have rather an easy life if I had succeeded in factoring out of $$x^0+x^1+x^2+x^4+.....$$ a common factor with 2 term polynomial. Sadly didn't manage to on this instance.

Comment: Note your defined function $f(x)$ of the first line of the display is immediately $[1/(1-x)-x^3]^6$ with no need of your remaining steps.

Comment: I would have defined $f(x)=({\sum_{k=0}^{13}}_{k \neq 3}(x^k))^{6}$ because you are using no negative number, you don't need infinite sum. If everything is right.

Comment: I have answered this question with Inclusion - Exclusion. My goal is to be able to attack it from generating functions approach.

Comment: @JonathanBarazi Curious: did you get $4092$?

Comment: Yes it's the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the coefficient needs to be manually extracted. Using the *coefficient of* operator $[x^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^k$ we obtain

> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[x^{13}]}&\color{blue}{\left(\frac{1}{1-x}-x^3\right)^6}\\
> &=[x^{13}]\sum_{k=0}^6\binom{6}{k}\frac{(-1)^kx^{3k}}{(1-x)^{6-k}}\\
> &=\binom{6}{0}[x^{13}]\frac{1}{(1-x)^6}-\binom{6}{1}[x^{10}]\frac{1}{(1-x)^5}+\binom{6}{2}[x^7]\frac{1}{(1-x)^4}\tag{1}\\
> &\qquad-\binom{6}{3}[x^4]\frac{1}{(1-x)^3}+\binom{6}{4}[x^{1}]{(1-x)^2}\\
> &=\binom{6}{0}\binom{-6}{13}(-1)^{13}-\binom{6}{1}\binom{-5}{10}(-1)^{10}+\binom{6}{2}\binom{-4}{7}(-1)^7\\
> &\qquad-\binom{6}{3}\binom{-3}{4}(-1)^4+\binom{6}{4}\binom{-2}{1}(-1)^1\tag{2}\\
> &=\binom{18}{5}-6\binom{14}{4}+15\binom{10}{3}-20\binom{6}{2}+15\binom{2}{1}\tag{3}\\
> &=8\,568-6\,006+1\,800-300+30\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=4\,092}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we apply the rule $[x^{p-q}]A(x)=[x^p]x^qA(x)$.
- In (2) we select the coefficient $[x^k]$ from the *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)* $[x^k](1-x)^{-\alpha}=[x^k]\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{-\alpha}{n}=\binom{-\alpha}{k}(-1)^k$.
- In (3) we use the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}(-1)^q=\binom{p+q-1}{p-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

The P.I.E approach needs to prepare some "ingredients".

There are solutions containing $4$ "bad" $x$'s, $3, 2, 1$ or none "bad" $x$'s.

The numbers involved are the following :

$$ {6\choose 4}{2\choose 1} = 30$$
$$ {6\choose 3}{6\choose 2} = 300$$
$$ {6\choose 2}{10\choose 3} = 1800$$
$$ {6\choose 1}{14\choose 4} = 6006$$
$$ {6\choose 0}{18\choose 5} = 8568$$

For example in $ {6\choose 2}{10\choose 3} $, $ {6\choose 2} $comes by requiring to have at least two bad $x$'s, which can be any two of the six $x$'s and ${10\choose 3} $ comes from stars and bars, while placing $13-3-3$ items in $4$ slots = $ {7+4-1\choose 4-1} $

This solution was not required, but the "coincidence" is worth noting.